# determine camera quality in android programmatically

Tags: android, camera, record

i wanna record videos with camera ( front camera ) but in different devices , the recording quality of front camera is different , and when we wanna record some videos with camera we have to set CamrecorderProfile for our MediaRecorder , the problem is that when i use CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_720P as CamrecorderProfile there is some devices that they front camera don't support 720P resolution.
and if we use QUALITY_LOW , we can record in all devices but in some devices the output video will be like this :

http://oi62.tinypic.com/153tr7k.jpg

so is there any way to find out the camera quality , so we can use proper quality to record in  every device

Answer (score 0):

You can check supported resolutions using the `Camera.Parameters` api http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html

Answer (score 0):

Ok Ill give you a quick code to start.With this code I'm getting best parameters available for any phone in which my application is installed so it won't stretch or show not smooth while capturing.The code you mostly will need is in `SurfaceChanged`

```
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // The Surface has been created, acquire the camera and tell it where to draw.
    try {
        mCamera = Camera.open(); // WARNING: without permission in Manifest.xml, crashes
                }
    catch (RuntimeException exception) {
        //Log.i(TAG, "Exception on Camera.open(): " + exception.toString());
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Camera broken, quitting :(",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        // TODO: exit program
    }

    try {
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        updateBufferSize();

        mCamera.addCallbackBuffer(mBuffer); // where we'll store the image data
        mCamera.setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer(new PreviewCallback() {
            public synchronized void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera c) {

                if (mCamera != null) { // there was a race condition when onStop() was called..
                    mCamera.addCallbackBuffer(mBuffer); // it was consumed by the call, add it back
                }
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        //Log.e(TAG, "Exception trying to set preview");
        if (mCamera != null){
            mCamera.release();
            mCamera = null;
        }
        // TODO: add more exception handling logic here
    }
}

public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // Surface will be destroyed when we return, so stop the preview.
    // Because the CameraDevice object is not a shared resource, it's very
    // important to release it when the activity is paused.
    //Log.i(TAG,"SurfaceDestroyed being called");
    mCamera.stopPreview();
    mCamera.release();
    mCamera = null;
}

// FYI: not called for each frame of the camera preview
// gets called on my phone when keyboard is slid out
// requesting landscape orientation prevents this from being called as camera tilts
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
    //Log.i(TAG, "Preview: surfaceChanged() - size now " + w + "x" + h);
    // Now that the size is known, set up the camera parameters and begin
    // the preview.
    try {
        mParameters = mCamera.getParameters();

           int picH = mParameters.getPictureSize().height;
             int picW = mParameters.getPictureSize().width;
             int preH = mParameters.getPreviewSize().height;
             int preW = mParameters.getPreviewSize().width;
             float scale = ((float)(picH*preW)) / ((float)(picW*preH));


             float bff = 0;
             try {
                 List<Camera.Size> supportedSizes = null;

                 //maximize supported resizes, TODO remove as hardcode
                 w*=1.5;
                 h*=1.5;

                 // On older devices (<1.6) the following will fail
                 // the camera will work nevertheless
                 supportedSizes = mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes();

                 // preview form factor
                 float ff = (float) w / h;
                 System.out.println("TAG" + "Screen res: w:" + w + " h:" + h + " aspect ratio:" + ff);

                 // holder for the best form factor and size
                 int bestw = 0;
                 int besth = 0;
                 Iterator<Camera.Size> itr = supportedSizes.iterator();

                 // we look for the best preview size, it has to be the closest
                 // to the
                 // screen form factor

                 while (itr.hasNext()) {
                     Camera.Size element = itr.next();
                     // current form factor
                     float cff = (float) element.width / element.height;
                     // check if the current element is a candidate to replace
                     // the best match so far
                     // current form factor should be closer to the bff
                     // preview width should be less than screen width
                     // preview width should be more than current bestw
                     // this combination will ensure that the highest resolution
                     // will win
                     Log.d("TAG", "Candidate camera element: w:"
                             + element.width + " h:" + element.height
                             + " aspect ratio:" + cff);
                     if ((ff - cff <= ff - bff) && (element.width <= w)
                             && (element.width >= bestw)) {
                         bff = cff;
                         bestw = element.width;
                         besth = element.height;
                     }
                 }
                 System.out.println("TAG" + "Chosen camera element: w:" + bestw + " h:" + besth + " aspect ratio:" + bff);
                 // Some Samsung phones will end up with bestw and besth = 0
                 // because their minimum preview size is bigger then the screen
                 // size.
                 // In this case, we use the default values: 480x320
                 if ((bestw == 0) || (besth == 0)) {
                     Log.d("Mixare", "Using default camera parameters!");
                     bestw = 480;
                     besth = 320;
                 }
                 mParameters.setPreviewSize(bestw,besth);
             } catch (Exception ex) {
                 mParameters.setPreviewSize(480,320);

                 bff=1.5f;
             }
             makeResizeForCameraAspect(bff);
        for (Integer i : mParameters.getSupportedPreviewFormats()) {
            //Log.i(TAG, "supported preview format: " + i);
        } 

        List<Size> sizes = mParameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
        for (Size size : sizes) {
        Log.i(VIEW_LOG_TAG, "supported preview size: " + size.width + "x" + size.height);
        }
        mCamera.setParameters(mParameters); // apply the changes
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // older phone - doesn't support these calls
    }

    updateBufferSize(); // then use them to calculate

    Size p = mCamera.getParameters().getPreviewSize();
    //Log.i(TAG, "Preview: checking it was set: " + p.width + "x" + p.height); // DEBUG
    mCamera.startPreview();
}

private void makeResizeForCameraAspect(float cameraAspectRatio) {
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams=this.getLayoutParams();
    int matchParentWidth=this.getWidth();
    int newHeight=(int)(matchParentWidth/cameraAspectRatio);
    if(newHeight!=layoutParams.height){
        layoutParams.height=newHeight;
        layoutParams.width=matchParentWidth;
        this.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        this.invalidate();
    }
}



public Parameters getCameraParameters(){
    return mCamera.getParameters();
}

public void setCameraFocus(AutoFocusCallback autoFocus){
    mCamera.getParameters();
    mCamera.getParameters();
    if (mCamera.getParameters().getFocusMode().equals(Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO) ||
            mCamera.getParameters().getFocusMode().equals(Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_MACRO)){
        mCamera.autoFocus(autoFocus);
    }
}
```